# Progress Bar for each process

Tags: c#, process, backgroundworker

I'm currently busy with a small C# application that reads a folder then dynamically lists all `.rar` files on a windows form with a dynamic progress bar next to each `.rar` file. So basically with the press of a button, the `.rar` files needs to be unzipped (winrar command line) showing the progress for each process.

Below is my process snippet

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"unrar.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = FileName + "whatever attributes/switches";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Having trouble getting this right.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: What does the `unrar.exe` binary output?  This is obviously relevant to determining the completion progress...

Comment: I can't get the progress bars to work together with the processes.

If I have for example 5 rar files, I need to run the first process with it's progress bar, once complete, moves over to the second process, etc.

Currently all processesruns/completes and then display all progress bars at once.

Comment: This is the output from the unrar

    UNRAR 4.00 beta 4 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2011 Alexander Roshal

    Extracting from filename.rar

    Extracting  d:\test\test\filename.mp4          0% 1%  2%  3%

    Extracting from filename.r00

    ...         filename.mp4      4%  5%  6%  7%

    Extracting from filename.r01

    ...         filename.mp4         8%  9% 10%

    ...
    ...
    ...

    Extracting from filename.r26

    ...         filename.mp4  98%   99%  OK 
    All OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If unrar.exe outputs the progress to the standard output, you could try and parse it to update the progressbar.

Instead of using unrar.exe to uncompress the archives from within your program, you could try using a library, like SevenZipLib http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that UNRAR doesn't output a NewLine, and just keeps writing to the same line, so the event handler never gets called. It only gets called once a new line is written.

I would go with Simon's solution and try to use 7zip instead. It's more friendly has a great C# library and works with almost all formats.